# Show XML data with d3js

Tags: javascript, xml, d3.js

i'm working on a little d3.js asignment for school.. I looked at some examples to load a XML file, but I can't figure it out what i'm doing wrong.. The XML file is loading correct.. I'm just figuring out JS so please not to technical ;p..

this is the code:

```
d3.xml("data.xml", "application/xml", function(xml) {

    var data = d3.select(xml).selectAll("path");

    console.log("data uit de xml=  " + data);

});
```

Thanx!

Comment: The use of d3.select may not be what you want, as that tries to 'connect' to data already in the Document Object Model (DOM). Perhaps just use "console.log(xml)" as a starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have `path` elements in your XML, you would select them like this:

```
var data = xml.path;
```

The XML data is returned as a JavaScript object. It might be easiest to log the entire object and look at it in the debugger/JavaScript console of the browser of your choice.